# With iTerm2 on Mac, how to delete forward a word from cursor on command-line?

Tags: macos, bash, special-characters, typing, iterm2

With iTerm2 1.0.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, I'd like to delete from cursor to the next end of word, i.e. deleting one word forward.  I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> but this types the delta operator symbol [`∂`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%82) and doesn't delete.  How to suppress the typing but let it delete?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't have a mac handy, but ESC d should in theory do the same thing that ALT-d does.

NOTE: this means hitting ESC, releasing it, then hitting d. Look ma, no key chords.

Comment: Correct; ESC typically acts as the meta key in Mac OS X, since the Alt key (Option) is used for other purposes.

Comment: Where to see a complete list of such key combinations for editing at command line?

Comment: meh. it works but it ain't so very comfortable on new machines where the ESC is a on the touch bar. seems like manually mapping this to Alt-d is the better choice.

Answer (score 77):

`Preferences` → `Profile` → `Keys` add the following shortcuts:

---

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ b

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ f

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [H

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [F

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←Delete</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x18 0x7f (add `bindkey "^X\\x7f" backward-kill-line` to `.zshrc` if  you use zShell)

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>←Delete</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x1B 0x08

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Del→</kbd> Send Hex Code 0x0b

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Del→</kbd> Send Escape Sequence d

Comment: ⌥←Delete : Send Hex Code 0x1B 0x08

to delete a word backwards till spl. character. 
( self notes )

Comment: If you're using Emacs and want to send Meta-d (delete next word) when pressing ⌘+d, then set: ⌘+d to Send Hex Code 0x1B 0x64.

Answer (score 19):

Just to add to Alexsander's answer the easiest way to replicate this behaviour is to select the option "Left option key acts as +Esc" in the Preferences->Profiles-> Keys screen.

Answer (score 14):

You can add a shortcut for it, go to "Preferences" → "Profiles" → "Keys", and then click on "+" to add a custom shortcut, and add this:

[image]

Now you should be able to delete a word forward by clicking <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

Even simpler solution is to go to "Preferences" → "Profiles" → "Keys" and in the "Presets..." dropdown, choose "Natural Text Editing"

Answer (score 6):

You can follow this [article](https://coderwall.com/p/ds2dha/word-line-deletion-and-navigation-shortcuts-in-iterm2) to set up the key binding in iterm2. It works for me.
The hex codes for...
Deleting a word: 0x17.
Deleting a line: 0x15.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Surprised no-one mentions this one, which works for me:

Settings -> Profiles -> Default (or whatever) -> Keys -> General -> Left Option key: switch from `Normal` to `Esc+`.

Comment: Did this in old one and somehow forgot this for my new mac book. This is simple. Now ALT +  back/forward arrow moves word. ALT + d delete word forward , ALT + backspace delete word behind the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

[maxbellec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218806/maxbellec) answer was really helpful, I'll just add that:

> ⌘← Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [H

> ⌘→ Send Escape Sequence Esc+ [F

did not do the trick for me.
First, these shortcuts were already configured in the `Preferences -> Keys -> Key Bindings` as other actions shortcut (next/previous tab). But changing these shortcuts to other combinations also did not work.
So, I've added:

> bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line

> bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line

to the `.zshrc`, which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+d` was a forward delete for me in `irb` and `iex` in iTerm2. But since I wanted to use the regular del key on the keyboard with the numpad, I looked for something else. And then I found a list of hex codes corresponding to ctrl+something key strokes: 4 is number and the number is 4. [image: iTerm2 Del key mapping]

Comment: This is forward delete a _character_, the question is about deleting a _word_

Comment: It closes terminal window as well. Not the best solution.